# Definion of the binomial coefficients in the set theory. Reference request for recursion principles.

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

The definition of the binomial coefficients is here:
$$\binom{n+1}{k+1}=\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k+1}$$
$$\binom{0}{0}=\binom{n}{n}=1$$
My aim is to define it in set theory on natural numbers, not on rational numbers like this $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.

let's do it by recursion on $n$.

1) Base:
$$n=0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad C_n=\{\langle 0,1\rangle\}$$
2) Step:
$$C_{n+1}(k)=?$$

Surely I can define it using usual recursion theorem and then restrict it to particular domain.

And here I may use some kind of "finite recursion" on $k$. (where I have both sides) 
How this principle can be formulated? (the output is function on a finite number). Maybe there are articles/books with some useful recursive principles? (I am also interested in mutual recursion and other recursion principles.)

Comment: What do you mean "in set theory"? There is no set theory here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But everything is a set theory! :-) More seriously, I am looking for recursion theorems, similar to the ones I familiar with: recursion on natural numbers and transfinite recursion. (I think I had not enough captured a concept, it is just a reference request...)